# How to give Onclick function to dynamic created button (Number of button will change every time)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating number of buttons depending upon length of records . So number of buttons will change when record will change every time I will run program. Here is my code of it .

```
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
<button type="button" id='+i+'>'+i+'</button>';
}
```

It will create buttons 1,2,3,4,5....up-to length of labels. Now problem is that I want to assign them id and onclick. On everyonclick It will pass value to a function which button was press like I will pass 1 if 1st button was pressed and 2 if 2nd button is pressed. How I can do it ? I saw that [Question that reported as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) question but he is using jquery and not passing any values to new function based on Id (which is my main problem) .

Comment: give them a class & get the attribute id from it on click

Comment: @AgamBanga I am new in javascript. Can you give a demo type thing please ? It would be great favor

Comment: @AgamBanga no its not. I have checked that one. I am not using plugin or AJAX etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button type="button" class="mybtn" id='+i+'>'+i+'</button>';
```

the button have a common class `mybtn` and with incremented `id` value in it.

And you can assign event listener to it like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mybtn', function(){
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );
    // Will give the id value for the clicked button
});
```

Comment: this button code will come in for loop ?? And onclick will outside for loop ?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct

Comment: `mybtn` is `.mybtn` as it is a class. Just slip of mind :P

Comment: thank you @Mayank Pandeyz . Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Below is something that you want:

```js
var buttons="";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  buttons+='<button type="button" id='+i+' onClick="alert('+i+');">'+i+'</button>';
}
document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = buttons;
```

```html
<div id="area"></div>
```

**UPDATE**
You can call any function in the onClick handler and pass any value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple javascript `onclick` function

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
document.body.innerHTML +='<button type="button" id='+i+' onclick="test(this)">'+i+'</button>';
}
 function test(that){
 console.log(that.id+'  was passed')
 
 }
```

Comment: let me check.it seems a good move

Answer (score 0):

Since this buttons are dynamically created you need to delegate the event

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   // some parent element to hold the buttons
  $('#buttonHolder').append('<button class ="buttonClass" type="button" id=' + i + '>' + i + '</button>');
}

 //on click delegate the event to button
$('body').on('click', '.buttonClass', function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='buttonHolder'></div>
```